# in my program when i write cin>>name[i] in class function its say expression must have pointer-to-object type

Tags: visual-c++

For that part `name[i]` it shows error. I want to store names of computer in a string array

```
using namespace std;

class computer
{ 
protected:
    string name[100];
    string model[100];
    int prize[100];
    string ram[100];
    int limit;
public:
    computer()
    {
        limit=0;
    }
    void name()
    {
        cout<<"Enter your desire records limit = ";
        cin>>limit;
        for(int i=0;i<limit;i++)
        {
           cout<<"Name = ";
           cin>>name[i];
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: You have a function `void name()` and a array  `string name[100]`. The names are clashing, you should rename your function to something else, like `getName`.

Comment: It's really unclear what your current question is asking.

Answer (score 0):

Change `name[i]` into `name` (`name[i]` means to let user enter a `char`)

and change the `name()` to `getname()`

Code:

```
using namespace std;

class computer
{ 
protected:
    string name[100];
    string model[100];
    int prize[100];
    string ram[100];
    int limit;
public:
    computer()
    {
        limit=0;
    }
    void getname()
    {
        cout<<"Enter your desire records limit = ";
        cin>>limit;
        for(int i=0;i<limit;i++)
        {
           cout<<"Name = ";
           cin>>name;
        }
    }
};
```